# Oracle sql sum column and return other columns

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

I have the following query where I need sum up the FTBR_QTY_FAILED by each day but also output the other columns. I have tried a few grouping options but I am unable to output the summed failed_qty for each day and the other column values.
Can anyone give me any direction/ideas on this:

```
<cfquery datasource="UKCHAPP145" name="Q4">
 SELECT
TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_QTY_FAILED AS TotalFailedQty,
    TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_TASK_UUID,
    TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_DATE,
    TBL_TASK.TASK_NAME,
TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_UUID
FROM
    UKCHAPP145.TBL_RESULTS,
    UKCHAPP145.TBL_TASK
WHERE
    TBL_TASK.TASK_UUID = TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_TASK_UUID
AND
    TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_TASK_UUID = '#URL.TASK_UUID#'
AND
to_char(TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_DATE, 'YYYY') = '#URL.YEAR#'
AND
TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_WEEK_NO = '#URL.WEEK_NUMBER#'
AND
TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_SHIFT IN (#ListQualify(URL.SHIFT,"'",",","ALL")#)
ORDER BY
    TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_DATE
ASC
</cfquery>
```

Here is some example data outputted by this query:

```
FTBR_DATE              FTBR_TASK_UUID  FTBR_UUID  TASK_NAME                   TOTALFAILEDQTY 
---------------------  --------------  ---------  -------------------------   --------------              
2015-03-09 00:00:00.0  19971           594052     LOW OR NO FLOW - 1BAR TEST  3  
2015-03-10 00:00:00.0  19971           594916     LOW OR NO FLOW - 1BAR TEST  4  
2015-03-11 00:00:00.0  19971           595828     LOW OR NO FLOW - 1BAR TEST  12  
2015-03-11 00:00:00.0  19971           595843     LOW OR NO FLOW - 1BAR TEST  1  
2015-03-12 00:00:00.0  19971           597209     LOW OR NO FLOW - 1BAR TEST  3  
2015-03-12 00:00:00.0  19971           597195     LOW OR NO FLOW - 1BAR TEST  13  
2015-03-13 00:00:00.0  19971           597859     LOW OR NO FLOW - 1BAR TEST  13
```

Many thanks

JC

Comment: Probably you are looking for `sum(TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_QTY_FAILED) over (partition by TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_DATE) AS TotalFailedQty` here.

Comment: yes tried a few variations of using group by but because FTBR_TASK_UUID is a unique value it wont group the dates up.

Comment: Tried: SUM(TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_QTY_FAILED) over (partition by TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_DATE) AS TotalFailedQty,

Comment: and get the same output, it doesn't group by date

Comment: `...over (partition by trunc(TBL_RESULTS.FTBR_DATE) order by null rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)` ? Sorry, it's hard to test as you did not provide sample data. Works on generated test data.

Comment: I see you added some data, but this time UUID's are not equal, which is part of `where` clause, and column order does not match query, so maybe you mixed something? ;-) Anyway I made [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9f41/1), maybe this will help. Last column is daily sum which interests you.

Comment: Providing output from the query which doesn't do want you want is not helpful.  I suggest you post some sample input data and the desired output.

Comment: FYI, I strongly suggest you use `<cfqueryparam>` ... Oracle is not as susceptible to SQL injection as SQL Server, but that doesn't mean it can't happen.

Comment: Before we can give you a better solution, we need to know: Do you need to capture the UUID? If so, how do you intend to get that with the count of the day? Do you want a row for each UUID and the sum for that date alongside it? Or do you want to show a delimited list of UUIDs for each date?